# Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy practicando android studio cuando trato de hacer correr mi proyecto me sale el siguiente error:

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

ademas de que me muestra una **x** donde se selecciona app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en esto ayuda porfa.

este es mi **buildgradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deivi.fastfood"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo todo instaldo

Comment: Tienes que revisar la ventana del compilador o el Event Log, que errores se muestran ahí? ya que tu build.gradle no da mucha idea de que pudiera suceder.

Comment: Podrías tomar captura completo del lado del buid